Single Primary Key vs. Composite Primary Key to store user isolated data
Let's say I want to store user provided data in a table called post.

users data are isolated by user_id column
select sum(likes_count) where user_id = $ should be fast
select * from post where id = $ should be fast

Could you help compare these schemas in terms of performance, indexing, and typical use cases?
note: char(24) values are MongoDB's ObjectId hex string. they are unique across database.
Schema 1:
using PRIMARY KEY (id) and secondary index on (user_id)
CREATE TABLE posts_v1 (
  id CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  user_id CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  likes_count INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY 'user_id_idx' (user_id)
);


using PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id) and secondary unique index on (id)
Schema 2:
CREATE TABLE posts_v2 (
  id CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  user_id CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  likes_count INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id),
  UNIQUE KEY 'id_idx' (id)
);


Questions:
1- In which scenarios would one schema perform better than the other? For example, queries that filter by user_id, id, or both.
2- Do posts_v2 schema uses less InnoDB page reads when querying by user_id? I assume in the case of posts_v2, table is physically grouped by user_id, so we can retrieve all users posts with less page scans, Is my assumption true?
3- Data Integrity and Maintenance: Are there any implications for data integrity, maintenance, or future schema evolution with either design?
4- Use Cases: What are the typical use cases or workloads that might favor one design over the other?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations you can provide!

(perhaps "identified by" instead of "isolated by"?)

Please provide some more columns of the table.  I would expect "post" to have some text and maybe a date.  You mentioned MongoDB and its char(24); is this being carried moved from MongoDB to MySQL?

@RickJames I use isolated word to say each user data are not related to another user. The table can also be sharded by user_id column.

Schema 2 is good for those queries.

PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id) is the key to making the "SUM" query faster.  In InnoDB, the PRIMARY KEY is clustered with the data.  select sum(likes_count) FROM ... where user_id = $ can simply run through a subset of the table to get the SUM for that one user.

select * from post where id = $ is a "point query".  So it will be fast enough if id is the first column of the PK a secondary index.  (PK would be faster, but we are talking about the order of a millisecond.)

"users data are isolated by user_id column" -- How much "isolation" do you want?  The above statements explain that you have enough for performance.


As for the 4 questions...

Size and page count are usually not worth measuring.
BTree nodes split in recombine in seemingly random ways.
Minimizing the pages needed for a query is the real goal.  I allude to that when suggesting that (user_id, ...) helps the SUM query.
I discuss the two queries above; if there are other "expensive" queries, I will analyze them.


Thanks! Do you have any resources to learn more about the design used for "Schema 2"? I'm not really sure about it, because i've never seen it before in any other DBs.

@ERFANIUM - I saw that a decade ago, and agreed with their rationale -- Something like, "most queries involve WHERE user_id = ?.  So having that PK(user_id, id) in InnoDB (which clusters the PK with the data) provides good "locality of reference".  Since then, I have suggested it a dozen times on StackExchange and StackOverflow (when appropriate).

Starting with question #3 - Data integrity: No, these two schemas are not the same. In fact, they are so much not the same, that other questions are not really relevant.
The table with PK on id would have unique value in the id field:
insert into posts_v1 (id, user_id) values(1, 'john')
insert into posts_v1 (id, user_id) values(2, 'john')
insert into posts_v1 (id, user_id) values(2, 'mary') -- error

But table with PK on user_id,id can have duplicate values in id field:
insert into posts_v2 (id, user_id) values(1, 'john')
insert into posts_v2 (id, user_id) values(2, 'john')
insert into posts_v2 (id, user_id) values(2, 'mary') -- not an error

But if you want to compare single-field PK with a multi-field PK: the single-field PK usually have better performance. There are exceptions, of course, but cases where multi-field has better performance are rare.
The more practical answer to your issue, would be: first, decide what is a natural key in your case, is it a multi-field or can it be a single-field? Go for what is better from business point of view, not from performance. After that, you can add a secondary unique index on the other field (or fields). That way you will get coverage for both type of queries - by one or multiple fields, regardless of are they part of PK or index.

Thanks. I updated my question. Post ids are globally unique. so having a user with duplicated post.id is not the case is my app
